# eclipse: start a tomcat project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

How can I start a tomcat project with eclipse?
I don't want a plugin that starts and stop my tomcat server, I just want to properly start a tomcat project and compile it.

any ideas?

I tried Eclipse Tomcat launcher plug-in by Sysdeo, doesn't seem to work properly with latest eclipse (javaee version). i can't start a new project.

Comment: Are you using [this eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/heliosr)?  Using this one it is easy to create a project that can deploy on Tomcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried working with the sysdeo plugin, but it's no use for me because i'm creating a tomcat project that will run on red5 so the plugin complains that i don't have any tomcat servers to start. but it seems that we don't realy need it.

the guy who commented your question is absolutely right.
using eclipse helios java ee version you can create a 'dynamic web project' which is a tomcat project. it's under the 'web' projects category.